# Is there a way to verify that mongodb is running in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

Currently my application uses MongoDB. If I send a request while mongo is not running it will wait 30 seconds before returning a Timeout Error. Is there a way that I can catch this while starting up my application?

Comment: how about using Java's Process utility to run ping command to your mongo host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with pinging the Socket:

```
public static void mongoIsConnected() throws Exception {
    String mongoUrlStr = "http://localhost:27017"; // mongo url
    URL mongoURL = new URL(mongoUrlStr);
    SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(mongoURL.getHost(), mongoURL.getPort());
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(socketAddress, 1000);
}
```

This will throw an error if mongo is not connected

Answer (score -2):

You can:

- Reduce the server selection timeout. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/ruby-driver-create-client/#development-configuration) for relevant development and production configuration guidance.
- Create another client with a low server selection timeout (e.g. 1) and perform a ping (issue `{ping:1}` using run command helper). This way you'll know within 1 second whether the deployment is up & running.